# I have a Route working fine with a GET and doing ERROR 404 for UPDATE and DELETE. What can I do?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Follow the code below, everything is working fine with other collections that I am using exactly the same code and handlerFactory as well with the GET call for this one but when I try to delete and update it is getting a 404 error, it is not a typo because GET is working well and the same in the handlerFactory.js as all CRUD operations are working fine with this same code and other collection:

app.js

```
var userRouter = require('./routes/userRoutes');
// Routes Definitions
app.use('/', viewRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/aircraft', aircraftRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter);
```

UserRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const userController = require('../controllers/userController');

const router = express.Router();



router.get('/', userController.getAllUsers);

router
  .get('/:id', userController.getUser)
  .delete(userController.deleteUser)
  .patch(userController.UpdateUser);

module.exports = router;
```

UserController.js

```
const user = require('../models/userModel');
const factory = require('./handlerFactory');

exports.getAllUsers = factory.getAll(user);
exports.getUser = factory.getOne(user);
exports.deleteUser = factory.deleteOne(user)
exports.UpdateUser = factory.updateOne(user);
```

handlerfactory.js

```
const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');
const AppError = require('../utils/appError');
const APIFeatures = require('../utils/apiFeatures');

exports.deleteOne = (Model) =>
catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
const doc = await Model.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);

if (!doc) {
  return next(new AppError('No document found with that ID', 401));
  console.log('No document found with that ID');
}

res.status(204).json({
  status: 'success',
  data: null,
});
});

exports.updateOne = (Model) =>
catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
const doc = await Model.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
  new: true,
  runValidators: true,
});

if (!doc) {
  return next(new AppError('No document found with that ID', 404));
}

res.status(200).json({
  status: 'success',
  data: {
    data: doc,
  },
});
});
```

Comment: You are missing `'/:id'` in your update and delete routs.

Comment: You are all right - I forget to use router.route('/:d).etc - to use like I was trying to use. In the same project, there was the answer - now I look like a fool :) - Thanks Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

I will answers my own question here because Daniel just come to my attention a silly mistake that I was making but I think it can still be useful to others.

If you just wanna one route per line use:

```
router.update('/:id', userController.updateOne);
```

If you are trying to use multiple routes in the same line do not forget to use .route like in the code below:

```
router.route('/:id').get(userController.getUser)
.delete(userController.deleteUser)
.patch(userController.UpdateUser);
```

Thank you very much, it may be silly but silly things happen with code every day.

Thank you all!